# Список популярных библиотек CAS на Java

Tags: java, android, library

Например: JAS (Java Algebra System). Вопрос в том, какие еще библиотеки существуют для использования? И какие из них можно использовать на Android?

Comment: Можно ссылку на список ?

Comment: А что, по вашему, такое CAS? Я так-то с пяток расшифровок могу накидать

Comment: Computer Algebra System (CAS)